# How it it possible to disbale all WooCommerce scripts and styles, but keep wc-ajax=get_refreshed_fragments working?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I disabled all styles and scripts for certain pages using the following code:

```
remove_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', [ WC_Frontend_Scripts::class, 'load_scripts' ] );
remove_action( 'wp_print_scripts', [ WC_Frontend_Scripts::class, 'localize_printed_scripts' ], 5 );
remove_action( 'wp_print_footer_scripts', [ WC_Frontend_Scripts::class, 'localize_printed_scripts' ], 5 );
```

As the question implies, the only thing, which has now disappeared, I want to keep working is the XHR AJAX calls to `wc-ajax=get_refreshed_fragments`. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look how that script is loaded in WC core

```
    'wc-cart-fragments'          => array(
        'src'     => self::get_asset_url( 'assets/js/frontend/cart-fragments' . $suffix . '.js' ),
        'deps'    => array( 'jquery', 'js-cookie' ),
        'version' => WC_VERSION,
    ),
```

You'll see the path to that script, as well as it's dependencies.  rebuild that path and enqueue it yourself.
FYI `$suffix` is set like this:

```
$suffix = defined( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG' ) && SCRIPT_DEBUG ? '' : '.min';
```